# Restangular remove not working (was: DJANGO: {"detail": "Method 'DELETE' not allowed."})

Tags: python, django, angularjs, restangular

check it the suffix needs to be:

```
RestangularProvider.setRequestSuffix('/?format=json');
```

otherwise django was tossing a redirect backed to the client, and while it worked - it was not correct.

---

The last change is to add:

```
RestangularProvider.setRequestSuffix('?format=json');
```

in your module definition, and to remove it from the service definition.  This way restangular can build the urls in a way that is expected by the django rest framework back-end.  Therefore a  service should be setup on the JS side as:

```
var spaceJam = angular.module('spaceJam', ['ui.bootstrap', 'restangular'])
            .config(function (RestangularProvider) {
                RestangularProvider.setRequestSuffix('?format=json');
                RestangularProvider.setResponseExtractor(function (response, operation) {
                     // blah
                     return response ;
                })
            })

spaceJam.factory('EventsResource', function (Restangular) {
    return Restangular.all('events')
})
```

injected into your controllers and accessed as a list:

```
EventsResource.getList().then(function(events){
                $scope.events = events
            })
```

and to remove an item (fire the HTTP Delete):

```
 $scope.events[someRandomIndex].remove()
```

and on the server side, you need to make sure the ID is being returned.  In django rest framework, this includes a solutions like the one below where a mixin is used to include the id.

Thanks for anybody who has put thought into this.

---

Making progress - apparently the url was being returned instead of the id.  This link http://abesto.net/django-rest-framework-add-id-to-in-hyperlinkedmodelserializer/ outlines adding a mixin o the the serializer that adds the id.in case the link doesn't work in the future, here is the relevant snippet:

```
class WithPkMixin(object):
    def get_pk_field(self, model_field):
        return self.get_field(model_field)

class EventSerializer(WithPkMixin, serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Event
```

I think the issue is now in my factory method of my resource / restangular resource definition as the Id is appended in the wrong place (i think because I was hacking originally):

```
  spaceJam.factory('EventsResource', function (Restangular) {
        return Restangular.all('events/?format=json')
    })
```

so the string '/?format=json' needs to be removed, and added back in at some other point.

---

Update looks like the method being sent is to root node. I am using angularjs and restangular my javascript looks like:

```
spaceJam.factory('EventsResource', function (Restangular) {
        return Restangular.all('events/?format=json')
    })

var CalendarListCtrl = function($scope, $timeout, EventsResource) {
        var timeout = 10000
        $scope.events = []

        $scope.refresh = function (){
            EventsResource.getList().then(function(events){
                $scope.events = events
            })
        }

        var asychUpdate = function(){
            $scope.refresh()
            //$timeout(asychUpdate, timeout);
        }
        asychUpdate()

        $scope.delete = function(urlToDelete) {

            var eventToDelete = _.find($scope.events, function(one) {
                return one.url === urlToDelete;
            });

            eventToDelete.remove();
            $scope.refresh()
        }

    }
```

so while the remove method looks to be documented as the way to remove an item from the list - it  doesn't seem to have the proper URL.

---

I am learning django / python as I build a site for a non-profit I am associated with.   I am able to issue the gets for the list / array of elements.  The "add" (post) method works, and now I am trying to hook up the delete.  My server response is :

```
{"detail": "Method 'DELETE' not allowed."}
```

So I assume that i need  to permission that verb - but I have no idea where.  I am using the DJANGO REST Framework. I haven't been able to locate this on google, so I am askng the kind and knowledgeable folks here. Thank you in advance, and please let me know if I need to post more code.

urls.py

```
router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'events', views.EventViewSet)

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    (r'^', include(router.urls)),
)
```

models.py

```
class Event(models.Model):
      title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
      recurring = models.BooleanField()
      day = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True)
      date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
      time = models.TimeField()
      description = models.CharField(max_length=500)
      venue = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
      venueAddress = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
      venueCity = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
```

serializers.py

```
class EventSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Event
```

views.py

```
class EventViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    paginate_by = None
    queryset = Event.objects.all()
    serializer_class = EventSerializer
```

Comment: What url are you hitting? If you're using something like `path/to/my/resource/` and not `path/to/my/resource/PK/` it won't know which object to delete.

Comment: Yes, it seems you are trying to delete root view, see tests: https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/tests/test_generics.py#L93

Comment: agree I am trying to delete the root node. Well, I am  using restangular to proxy the API - so lets see what that is doing.  While I followed an example, that  has always proven fool proof.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer in original post but includes

1. making sure the ID is returned in the rest services and that
2. the angular factory that encapsulates the restangular resource is done such that the URL can be built dynamically, which includes
3. moving any URL parameters to the request suffix.